# install4j Updater - cmdline parameters missing after restart

Tags: java, install4j

Imagine the installation of an Install4J based application is done.
Imagine that the installed exe-file is started with some additional commandline parameters.
Now the Updater kicks in, downloads and installs a new version, and restarts
the application's exe file, but the cmdline parameters are gone / not passed into the restarted application.

Is there a way to preserve those parameters for the restart after update?

I'm talking about Install4J 7.0.5, and in my case the BGUpdater is called via API (but I guess it's the same if it runs automatically in the background
and schedules installation for next application start).

Answer (score 1):

The executable is restarted with the "Execute launcher" action in of the downloaded installer. That action does not know what arguments the executable was started with originally.

In your application, you would have to save the arguments so that the new installer can access them, for a example in the Java preference store. In the installer, you can use a "Read a key from the Java preference store" action to save the arguments to an installer variable, say to "lastArguments". Then you can set the "Arguments" property of the "Execute launcher" action to `${installer:lastArguments}`.

---

**Update for 7.0.9+:**

A new method

```
UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(
    List<String> updaterArguments, 
    boolean restartLauncher, 
    List<String> launcherArguments, 
    Runnable shutdownRunnable
)
```

has been added that allows you to pass arguments for the launcher when it is restarted.

> but I guess it's the same if it runs automatically in the background and 
>    schedules installation for next application start

No, in case of the automatic update the original parameters for the launcher are always passed when the launcher is restarted, also before 7.0.9.

Comment: For future readers:

From 7.0.9 there will be a version of `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate` that takes an argument `launcherArguments`. Where you can pass the cmdline arguments to the launcher (Thanks @Ingo for helping med with this!)